# Stacked FusionCharts label position

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts to show a stacked 2D column chart. The positioning of the label at the top of the bar seems to be very unpredictable. It is at times inside, outside or even somewhere in between with the top border cutting off the text.

Is there a way for me to specify that I always want it to be outside and have a certain margin so that it never touches the bar?

Thanks.

[Screenshot of label being cut-off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZtbH.gif)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for label appearing, inside, outside or overlapping is FusionCharts always try to place its label outside of the plots. But if the labels goes outside canvas, Which happens when the plot almost as high as the canvas, it tries to position it dynamically. Labels can not go outside of Canvas.

One way to fix this is to set the Y axis max value a bit higher, And that will give enough place to draw the labels outside of plots. Also this attribute [`placeValueInside`](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=column2d&attributeName=chart_placeValuesInside) is related to this problem.